# Relativistic Dynamical System

Tags: quantum-field-theory, special-relativity

I have read in a paper that:

A relativistic dynamical system must be invariant under infinitesimal inhomogeneous Lorentz transformation. A dynamical system is characterized by the ten generators, $P^\mu$ and $M^{\mu\nu}$, of the Poincare group, where $P^\mu$ is the momentum 4-vector and $M^{\mu\nu}$ is the rotation and boost operators.

Here, what does 'A relativistic dynamical system' mean?

Reference: http://inspirehep.net/record/514295?ln=en (page: 95)

Comment: Please post the source of the quote. (Please do this whenever you quote from anything, under any circumstances, ever.)

Comment: The reference is given.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking we can say that a (quantum) relativistic dynamical system indicates a quantum system defined on a Hilbert space admitting a unitary (strongly continuous) representation of Poincaré group (at least the proper orthochronous subgroup). This unitary representation must include the unitary time evolution of the system as a one-parameter subgroup.